# C# Oracle convert to bulk upload

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have existing c# code that I want to convert into a bulk insert.

I want to use array binding but all my data is held into lists of strings.  What is the best way to convert this oracle stored proc call to handle bulk inserts?

here is the code

```
               for (int i = 0; i < listSize.Count(); i++)
              {
              using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
              {
                OracleConnection conn;
                conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringOracle);

                cmd.CommandText = "package.insertR";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oRetValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("firstList", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767));
                cmd.Parameters["firstList"].Value = rd.fl[i];
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("secondList", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767));
                cmd.Parameters["secondList"].Value = rd.sl[i];
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                  conn.Close();
               }
```

the sample insert in plsql is

```
 PROCEDURE insertr(
      oRetValue OUT varchar2,
      firstListIN   varchar2,           
      secondList IN   varchar2,) AS
BEGIN
 insert into tablename (first1,second1)
values (firstList,secondList);
 END insertr;
```

Comment: Please include the source code for your PL/SQL procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
          {
            OracleConnection conn;
            conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringOracle);
            cmd.ArrayBindCount = listSize.Count();
            cmd.CommandText = "package.insertR";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":firstList", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767));
            cmd.Parameters[":firstList"].Value = rd.fl.ToArray();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":secondList", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767));
            cmd.Parameters[":secondList"].Value = rd.sl.ToArray();
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
              conn.Close();
```